How to migrate Existing Android app to Instant App , i am unable to do it since size is getting around 70MB
I followed below link of Android.
https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/feature-module-migration
After using this facing alot of issues in manifest and gradle .
Error

[:installedfeature, :installedfeature] all package the same library [androidx.browser:browser;Capability: group='androidx.browser', name='browser'].
[:installedfeature, :installedfeature] all package the same library [androidx.credentials:credentials;Capability: group='androidx.credentials', name='credentials'].
[:installedfeature, :installedfeature] all package the same library [androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface;Capability: group='androidx.exifinterface', name='exifinterface'].


:app module
dependencies {
implementation ('androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1')
implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
}


:installedfeature module was base module before but now i changed it to app: module as mentioned in android official doc.
if i add all my libs here in :app module then it is fixed but then android resource linking failed manifest issue occurs
Unable to understand how to do this.
